# $m$-$n$ Theorem of triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Consider the following theorem

[image]

For the given triangle and the mentioned attributes of it,
$$ (m+n)\cot\theta = m\cot\alpha - n\cot\beta$$

I am looking for the symmetric intuition behind this theorem. What is the hidden symmetry that underlies it

Comment: Hint: Project $\vec{CB}  = \vec{AB} - \vec{AC}$ onto $\vec{AD}$.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The statement reflects

\begin{align}
PQ = AQ - AP
\end{align}
which is
$$(b+c)(- \cot \theta ) = c\cot \beta -b \cot \alpha
$$

where $\frac{b}{c} = \frac mn$ per triangle similarity.