What ways do you use intuitively understand or memeorize M-N cot theorem?
$(m-n) \cot$ theorem is very simple. it is $$(m + n) \cot θ = m \cot \alpha – n \cot \beta$$ $$\text {or}$$ $$(m + n) \cot θ = n \cot B – m \cot C$$
             
             
             
             
    
                                                                     for a standard triangle.
I know this is easy to memorize, but unlike most of geometric theorems, the proof is quite long (using sin theorem) so, this theorem is not that intuitive to me. I don't see the theorem and feel like this is true. I tried to prove this using vectors and coordinate geometry to get a short proof or more intuitive way to see this theorem, but both attempts were similar in length to others and not that intuitive. I tried drawing perpendicular line segments to the sides of the triangle to see if I could find equal or proportional triangles by scaling them but failed.
So, I would like to know if someone has a short intuitive way or proof, that you use to memorize and understand (I understand this equation. I am looking for a way to get a quick feel of the theorem at a glance) m-n cot theorem.

Have you seen this proof? The vector projection mentioned in the comments also works, making these a "one-idea proof".

"the proof is quite long (using sin theorem)" Please include (or at least outline) the proof you've seen, so that people don't duplicate an approach you find unappealing.

@CalvinLin thanks. I couldn't see that correlation since I was focused on the same idea. That proof is fantastic.

@Blue it's just the general approach to prove this theorem. It's not something I came up with.  You can just google it or watch it on YouTube. However, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3681515/m-n-theorem-of-triangles answered my question

@donthababakka: "You can just google it or watch it on YouTube." Making people put time and effort into searching the web isn't particularly helpful, especially since the proof(s) we find might not match the one(s) you've and we wouldn't know what you find unsatisfactory about those that do. Providing in-question context is better all around. (There's a nice rule of thumb about this kind of thing: Always treat the reader's time as more important than your own. This is especially true when you're asking the reader for assistance.) In any case, I'm glad you have your answer. Cheers!
